# IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21]

Tags: python-3.x, directory

I received this error when attempting to uzip. Per the traceback this *.a is a directory. Is it possible to export everything in the directory to a different location?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 IsADirectoryError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-1-0217f0dffb9d> in <module>()
  1 import zipfile
  ----> 2 zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile('mask-rcnn-resnet50-ver-01.a', 'r')
  3 zip_ref.extractall('../output/0180306/build')
  4 zip_ref.close()

  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, 
  compression, allowZip64)
  1088             while True:
  1089                 try:
  -> 1090                     self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
  1091                 except OSError:
  1092                     if filemode in modeDict:

  IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'mask-rcnn-resnet50-ver- 
  01.a'
```

Comment: you ever figure this one out? i am ggeting the same issue

Comment: My apologies Dap. I think I took a different approach. It's been so long ago.

Comment: haha! all good! thanks for responding